# get_dummies does not have columns attribute

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

This line of code:

```
for j in range(0,len(names)):
  #fullSet = pandas.get_dummies(fullSet,columns=[names[j]])
  fullSet = pandas.get_dummies(fullSet,columns=[categoricalNames.columns[j]])
```

Is generating this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "noPrintsMachineLearnOptions.py", line 109, in <module>
    fullSet = pandas.get_dummies(fullSet,columns=[categoricalNames.columns[j]])
TypeError: get_dummies() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'
```

This code runs on my machine with Python 2.7.12 without issue, but on my work's server with Python 2.7.13 I get the above error.  There are countless examples on the web where `columns` is used with `get_dummies` so I do not understand what the problem is.

Comment: Are they using the same version of pandas?

Comment: It turns out no, where the code works is using "u'0.20.3'" and where it doesn't is using ''0.13.1".  Do older versions of pandas not support selecting columns in get_dummies?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `columns` argument for `get_dummies` was introduced in pandas version 0.15. Therefore, if you are using a version < 0.15 (e.g.  [version 0.14](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.0/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)), using `columns` will produce the error.

The solution would be to install the latest version of pandas